# How to convert the drupal-entity tag into an img tag?

Tags: media, wysiwyg, 8

I have a content type with a text field that uses CKEditor, in the editor is possible to add a media entity image, once the image is inserted inside the text the html tag for it is:

```
<p>Document</p>\r\n\r\n<drupal-entity alt=\"Luz\" data-embed-button=\"media_browser\" data-entity-embed-display=\"media_image\" data-entity-embed-display-settings=\"{&quot;image_style&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;}\" data-entity-type=\"media\" data-entity-uuid=\"4076130e-9ccb-43f1-a4d9-dc8176271ffa\" title=\"Luz\"></drupal-entity>\r\n
```

I have in the site a webservice that need to provide the text field with all the information, but I need to convert the drupal-entity tag into an img tag to provide a tag that can be used from the applications that use the webservice.

I made a search inside the CKEditor configurations and in the media module but I can't find any related to this, how can I convert the drupal-entity tag into an img tag?

Comment: This should be done by applying a text format which has the "Display embedded entities" text filter enabled.

Comment: I have the text format applied but is the same. I can see the image without problems but the field value is the same.

Comment: If you still see the token then the text filter @Hudri mentioned is not applied. So this is either a configuration problem in the text format or the webservice doesn't use the processed field output, a feature added to core recently, see ["processed" property of text fields now available in REST](https://www.drupal.org/node/2930012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll want to get the field's value and do a [str_replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp), but where?

I haven't done this myself yet, but I believe you'll have to create a normalizer.

[Serialization API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/serialization-api-overview) (good read).

I think you can achieve it by doing the following [Changing the way Serializer handles entities](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/changing-the-way-serializer-handles-entities).

There is more indepth info here [Using Normalizers to Alter REST JSON Structure in Drupal 8](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/using-normalizers-alter-rest-json-structure-drupal-8/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check the links and if I found the answer I will write some feedback.